# Refer generic without type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I am creating a tree structure in Scala, trying to implement the following type restrictions:

1. Non-root nodes are one of three types - Time Node, Start Node or End Node
2. Root node only has children of type Time Node
3. Time Nodes only have children of type Start Node
4. Start Nodes only have children of type End Node
5. End nodes may have children of type Start Node or Time Node

These are my type definitions:

```
trait TreeNode[U] {
val children:HashSet[NonRootNode[U]]
  def addChild(c:NonRootNode[U])
}

class NonRootNode[T <: TreeNode[T]] extends TreeNode[T] {
  var passengers:Set[Passenger] = Set()
  val children:HashSet[T] = new HashSet[T]
  def addChild(c:T) = {
    children.add(c)
  }
}

case class RootNode extends TreeNode[TimeNode] {
    val children:HashSet[TimeNode] = new HashSet[TimeNode]
    def addChild(c:TimeNode) = {
      children.add(c)
    }
}

case class TimeNode(time:Int) extends NonRootNode[StartNode] {

}

case class StartNode(l:Option[String]) extends NonRootNode[EndNode] {

}

case class EndNode(l:Option[String]) extends NonRootNode {

}
```

First, does this implement requirements 1-4 correctly? 
Second, is there a way to implement requirement 5 here in the definition? Is there ANY way to implement this requirement, as this would require a heterogeneous set to store children references.

EDIT: Types RootNode and EndNode would need a method like the following:

```
trait ParentOfTimeNode extends TreeNode{
  //type ChildType = TimeNode
  def addTimeNodes(startTime:Int, maxTime:Int) = {
      for(i <- startTime to maxTime) {
        this.addChild(new TimeNode(i))
      }
    }
}
```

Without that line commented, the line that screams is:

```
case class EndNode(l:Option[String]) extends NonRootNode with ParentOfTimeNode{ type ChildType = NonRootNode with IntervalMarker }
```

because of an obvious type match.
With the line commented, this.addChild screams since it is bound by ChildType which is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I can achieve your aim, but using type members rather than type parameters.

Also, this meant I could move the implementation of addChild into the trait and not re-implement it in the subclasses.

Finally, I added a marker trait, `IntervalMarker`, to label the two node types that EndNode can accept as children.

```
trait TreeNode {
  type ChildType <: NonRootNode
  val children:HashSet[ChildType] = new HashSet[ChildType]
  def addChild(c:ChildType) = {
    children.add(c)
  }
}

abstract class NonRootNode extends TreeNode {
  var passengers:Set[Passenger] = Set()
}

case object RootNode extends TreeNode { type ChildType = TimeNode }

trait IntervalMarker

case class TimeNode(time:Int) extends NonRootNode with IntervalMarker { type ChildType = StartNode }

case class StartNode(l:Option[String]) extends NonRootNode with IntervalMarker { type ChildType = EndNode }

case class EndNode(l:Option[String]) extends NonRootNode { type ChildType = NonRootNode with IntervalMarker }
```

Comment: Almost there. Now I have a method called addTimeNodes() which should be able to accept either a RootNode or a EndNode as a parameter (as these are the two types of Nodes that accept children of type TimeNode). I defined a trait WithTimeChildren which both RootNode and EndNode classes implement.
What should be the signature of the addTimeNodes method? addTimeNodes(node:TreeNode with WithTimeChildren) complains about type mismatch with node.ChildType when I try to pass a TimeNode to node.addChild, which is basically because the compiler does not know what the ChildType can be in this case.

Comment: @navjotk Not sure what you want here exactly - is addTimeNode a method on one of the TreeNode types? Can you maybe show some more code (or ask as a new question)?

Comment: @navjotk Hmm, you can get it to compile by changing the type value in the new trait to give bounds rather than an exact definition: `type ChildType >: TimeNode <: NonRootNode`. I haven't tested this thoroughly, though. See how you go.